# Confused about the implications of the continuum assumption of fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

Is the [continuum assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics#Assumptions) saying that we can model the actual fluid as being physically continuous? Or is it just saying that we can use spatial averaging around points in the fluid so that the field variables are continuous in space (but the physical fluid itself remains non-continuous)?